# Spring Boot Redirect if page not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application, where all 404 errors redirect to a certain page. I have read in various places that that *should* work like this:

`MyErrorController.java`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNoHandlerFoundException() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html");
    }
}
```

I have also added `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true` to my `application.properties` file.

...but it doesn't. All I get is the whitelabel error page when I enter a string without an endpoint, say `/garxms`.

I've also frequently read that the project structure might be the problem, but I don't think that's the case here since my main class is at the root level.

`MyProject.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProject{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyProject.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
MyProject
├Controllers
│├MyErrorController.java
│└MainController.java
├MyProject.java
└[...]
```

Checking out many similar topics here (many rather old), I have also tried a bunch of other approaches, such as:

`MyErrorController.java`

```
@Component
public class MyErrorController extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView doResolveException(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler,
        Exception ex
    ) {
        if (ex instanceof NoHandlerFoundException) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`MyErrorController.java`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(
        NoHandlerFoundException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(
            new ModelAndView("redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html"),
            HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }
}
```

`MainController.java`

```
    @GetMapping("/404")
    public RedirectView redirectOn404() {
        return redirectToSwaggerPage();
    }
```

...but none of them worked in my case for some reason. I have also tried disabling the whitelabel error page, but in that case I only see a 404 page instead.

So, what am I doing wrong here? It feels like no matter which way I'm trying to do it, the ControllerAdvice/Component/Whatever is never executed, and instead SpringBoot redirects me to the `/error` endpoint. I used to have an `ErrorController` that simply redirected to that page, but that caused problems when I added authentication because it also redirected to that page on a 403 error. I want only 404 errors to be redirected to the Swagger page.

Comment: are you sure that handleNoHandlerFoundException() is never called? I'm asking because we're handling the 404 error in the same way and it does work.

Comment: @dsp_user : Well, yeah, reasonably so. I mean, either that, or something else is not working here. The point is all the posts and tutorial pages I found say it should work like this, but for some reason it does not for me, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It's probably some little thing somewhere, but I can't figure it out